# Failed to use external js file in vue js, tried in mounted to append in head but its not working

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use an HTML admin template into vue cli. There are some js file in that template. When I trying in vue js they are working after refresh but when I am going one component to another they are not working.

For example: jquery.min.js etc.

```
mounted () {
let jqueryscript = document.createElement('script')
jqueryscript.setAttribute('src', '/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')
document.body.appendChild(jqueryscript) }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/pBzexp?editors=1010) should do the trick.  Keep in mind, this will fail if the URL you are providing in the `src=%url%` does not exist, or is unreachable (at least on CodePen)..

Full Link:
https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/pBzexp?editors=1010

---

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Wait for 2 seconds!</h1>
    <br />
    <h1>You will receive an alert.</h1>
    <br />
    <h1 style="color: red;">Click "Run" to run again!</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**JS/Vue:**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var newScript = document.createElement("script");      
      newScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
      var message = document.createElement("script");
      var alert = document.createTextNode("alert('Added jQuery Script Tag!');");
      message.appendChild(alert);
      document.body.appendChild(newScript);
      document.body.appendChild(message);
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

---

***Success!***

[image]